# Find equivalent resistanse

Tags: resistance

I am prepairing for my final exam, and the hardest topic for me to understand is finding equivalent resistance. So here is an example task. How to simplify this circuit to see where is parallel and where is in series?
[image]

UPD: My attempt to simplify this
[image]

Comment: What. Have. You. Tried? Show. Us. Your. Attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for Thevenin pairs. Can you read what I did?

[image]

Comment: i think i see now. does it mean that my attempt is right?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .